# Link text over 70 characters fail to render in comments

Tags: bug, comments, markdown-rendering

I was trying to make a comment like this

```
When you are banned from asking questions then you should read 
[what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers]
(https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/) carefully.
```

Which should render to

> When you are banned from asking questions then you should read [what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/) carefully.

But link texts **greather than 70 characters** fail to render in comments.

### Edit

This is how I made the comment

1. Copy the link of the question I want to link in my favorites tab ([What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)
2. Pasting that link in the comment field
3. Cutting out the part after the last slash in the link (*what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers*) and putting it between the *[ ]*

Comment: Test: 
[what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/)

Comment: While this is a bug, can't you just write a shorter link title?

Comment: Of course I can. I just wanted to complain about something :)

Comment: Test: [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”? Look ma, I can go an unlimited number of characters in my link text so long as it still fits within the maximum comment length.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/)

Comment: Test 2 [what can I do when getting sorry we are no longer accepting questions answers]
(http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/)

Comment: @animuson: Hmm. How did you do that?

Comment: @juergend: Are you sure you don't have weird characters in between the `]` and `(`?

Comment: @animuson: I removed characters from the link text I tried and it worked with less than 71 characters. No special characters involved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the culprit:

> [image: Zero-width non-joiners are a *****]

There is no character limit for links. There are hidden characters after your opening parenthesis, which causes the link after it to get auto-linkified, and the identification text before it is rendered as normal text.

This is probably some weird side-affect of SE adding zero-width spacers in between text to break long blocks of text that might overflow the screen. *Random Guess*

Solution: Don't do that. SE could linkify things *first*, but I still say don't do that.

---

**Confirming my suspicions:** As you can see in this second screenshot, adding more characters to the long block of non-breaking text causes the zero-width spacers to appear inside the actual identifier rather than immediately after the parenthesis.

> [image: So much fun!]

Comment: [what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/) `<--` Not a copy paste, I typed that out manually. The hidden characters get added automatically.

Comment: [what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-more-dashes-dashes-dashes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/)

Comment: culprit should be arrested and jailed:P